# Rails 3.0.3 and InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rack, middleware

I am, from only some users, getting a InvalidAuthenticityToken exception. When I examine the error I can see that the request has `"\r\n"` added to the authenticity_token parameter (ie: `"authenticity_token"=>"YfYr7bzy1MFzNHPvrSOIdrYuuAG3SHZy/OBJyV3yUSg=\r\n"`).

I don't know anything about the browser other than that it is IE7.

I have a feeling it is their firewall doing something to the request. I think a smart solution would be to create a Rack middleware that removes the line breaks if they exist. Can anyone show me how that would be done? (I have NO Rack experience).

Regards,

Jacob

Comment: I don't have the answer but I've read about general problems with IE and the authenticity token before. Until you get an answer here, I recommend more Web and mailing list searching.

Comment: Ok - thanks for the tip. I have done nothing but searching for the answer and for some reason I find nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have investigated and I can find no solution for this. It is not IE or IE7 in particular. I ended up making the following middleware:

```
class AuthenticityTokenFix
  def initialize(app)
    @app=app
  end

  def call(env)
    if env["rack.request.form_hash"] && env["rack.request.form_hash"]["authenticity_token"]
      env["rack.request.form_hash"]["authenticity_token"]=env["rack.request.form_hash"]["authenticity_token"].gsub("\r\n",'')
    end
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

That solved the problem.